# Альтернатива fancybox

Tags: jquery, javascript

Когда то находил неплохой jquery плагин замена fancybox, теперь не могу вспомнить.
Плагин увеличивает не саму картинку, а показывает в модальном окне html блок. Просьба подкинуть варианты, которые реализуют то, что fancybox но с html дивом, а не просто картинкой.

Answer (score 1):

[ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)